# basel-real exists, but when I run basel, it said "No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line

I downloaded and installed basel following the guide from the [page](http://bazel.io/docs/install.html), installer link is https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.0/bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh.

After install when I run basel, output is:

```
/usr/local/bin/bazel: line 86: /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real: No such file or directory
```

Line 86 of "/usr/local/bin/bazel" is:

```
exec -a "$0" "${BAZEL_REAL}" "$@"
```

But `/usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real` exists:

```
ll /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 103M Jan  1  1980 /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real

file /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real
/usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[md5/uuid]=51e0bd3d3319cc75ae66be80be63ac4e, not stripped
```

ldd

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real     
    not a dynamic executable
```

My linux version:

```
uname -r
4.4.0-x86_64-linode63
```

Comment: output is "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: For anybody else who wants to take a crack at this, here's what I got: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15381599/

Comment: I was testing on Arch Linux system, so the `ldd` output for Ubuntu would be different. Here's one from 14.04: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15381696/ Sorry about the mixup.

Comment: which user are you running this program with and which rights has the '/usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real' file?

Comment: @syss root, and -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root

Comment: pls post output of: `lsb_release -a` / `ldd -v /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real` please post the command with all arguments you used to install bezel and which user id use used therefor. Please run `sudo /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real' and post the result.

Comment: it is very strange, that the binary ist from1980.... pls post output of `stat /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real`

Comment: Please execute the following commands and post the output of the install and of ldd command:     `mkdir $HOME/testbazel`,  `cd $HOME/testbazel`, `wget "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.0/bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh"`, `chmod 0755 bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`, `sudo ./bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=$HOME/testbazel`, `ldd -v lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real`

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# stat /usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real
  File: ‘/usr/local/lib/bazel/bin/bazel-real’
  Size: 107708935  Blocks: 210592     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 800h/2048d Inode: 6259094     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-03-14 08:46:56.000000000 +0800
Modify: 1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0800
Change: 2016-03-11 17:21:01.000000000 +0800
 Birth: -

Comment: It is a little out of left-field but you have installed the required Java and if you are running Wily the specified dependencies?

Comment: @Tinyfool: Please edit your question an paste all the information that may help me to help you. Post them in a comment is not such easy to read. Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot reproduce your problem on Trusty Tahr, and in fact I have installed bazel with absolutely no issue, I will give here the steps I took to produce a working copy. Hopefully in reading this you may see where you may have gone wrong...

**Prerequisites:**

bazel is officially supported on Trusty Tahr and Wily Werewolf only at the moment and prerequisites are slightly different for each:

1. On Trusty Tahr OpenJDK 8 is not available and can be installed from this PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   ```
2. On Wily Werewolf you will need the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip
   ```

Note that I have tested on Trusty Tahr only...

**Building:**

Then for either Ubuntu release create a build directory and download the install file to it:

```
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/bazel_build && cd $HOME/Desktop/bazel_build
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.0/bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
```

Set the permissions and then install to the default `/usr/local`:

```
chmod +x bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
sudo ./bazel-0.2.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
```

**Testing:**

And then run `bazel` as follows:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ /usr/local/bin/bazel version
Build label: 0.2.0
Build target: bazel-out/local_linux-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Tue Feb 23 13:08:29 2016 (1456232909)
Build timestamp: 1456232909
Build timestamp as int: 1456232909
```

Hopefully you can see any shortcomings in your own build when observing this trouble free installation...

**References:**

- [Installing Bazel](http://bazel.io/docs/install.html)